# perl - optimal way to process many similarly named text files

Tags: perl

I have several thousand text files in a directory i need to process.
Similarly named, but with some variation:

```
/home/dir/abc123.name.efg-joe_p000.20110124.csv
/home/dir/abc456.name.efg-jon_p000.20110124.csv
/home/dir/abc789.name.efg-bob_p000.20110124.csv
```

I have a perl script that can process one file at a time without a problem:

```
./script.pl /home/dir/abc123.name.efg-joe_p000.20110124.csv
```

What's the best way to pass in and process many of these files, one a time? Am I looking at ARGV for this?
Should I list the files in a separate file and then use that as input?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If by "optimal" you mean "no code changes," and you are, as your pathnames suggest, on a *NIX-like system, try this:

```
$ find /home/dir -type f -name \*.csv -exec ./script.pl {} \;
```

If `script.pl` can handle multiple filename arguments, you might parallelize, say, 10 at a time:

```
$ find /home/dir -type f -name \*.csv | xargs -n 10 ./script.pl
```

Comment: this works. pretty neat! yes, optimal as not much code to change.

Answer (score 4):

You can pass a file pattern, as a parameter (glob format) and then pass that to `glob` call to list the files; then process them in a loop one by one.

```
./script.pl -file_pattern "/home/dir/abc123.name.efg-joe_p000.*.csv"
```

In your script

```
my @files = glob($file_pattern);
```

Comment: FYI: the difference looks like it was in the username (eg joe,jon,bob), not the date

Comment: wouldn't it be simpler to just do foreach my $file (@ARGV) { blah; }

Comment: how do you pass multiple file names to @ARGV?

Comment: I think what Fred Strauss means is that the shell can do wildcard expansion so that `@ARGV` has the complete list of files that match the pattern from the command line.

Comment: @Fred - 2 different approaches. I like mine because it's easier to convert current code that opens 1 file into this, AND I dislike @ARGV processing in general (not extensible/flexible enough)

Comment: Above example probably won't work, as the shell will do wildcard expansion.  You probably need to make that: `./script.pl -file_pattern '/home/dir/abc123.name.efg-joe_p000.*.csv'`.

Comment: @mscha - meh. my bad. fixed. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `readdir` to read the filenames one at a time:

```
opendir my $dh, $some_dir or die "can't opendir $some_dir: $!";

while (defined(my $file = readdir($dh))) {
    next if $file =~ /^\./;
    print $file;
}
```

Comment: Make sure you check for the '.' and '..' entries.

Comment: yes, i saw that on print. not sure how to filter those out. don't need hidden files to process.

Comment: With Perl 5.12 you can write it `while(readdir $dh){print "$_\n"}`

Comment: you can add `next if ($file =~ /^\.+$/);` after the `while` line to avoid . and ..

Comment: @Brad Thanks, good to know. I wonder why [perl5120delta](http://perldoc.perl.org/perl5120delta.html) doesn't mention this

Comment: A note to the future reader, the updated version of this code ignores all files/folders that begin with a `.`. This may well be what you want, just know that it is different from my comment above